# Set a Value for JAXBElement<String>

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a generated class that looks like below.  I need to call setAmount() from a POJO, but I don't know what value to pass for the arg.   It takes type JAXBElement, and I haven't found a way to instantiate that.

I have an ObjectFactory, but it only creates the class CardRequest.

Can anyone suggest a way?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "amount",
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "card-request")
public class CardRequest {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "amount", namespace = "http://mycompany/services", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<String> amount;

    public JAXBElement<String> getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.amount = ((JAXBElement<String> ) value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
JAXBElement<String> jaxbElement = 
    new JAXBElement(new QName("http://mycompany/services", "amount"), String.class, "Hello World");
```

There should also be a create method on the generated `ObjectFactory` class that will create this instance of `JAXBElement` with the appropriate info for you.

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement<String> jaxbElement = objectFactory.createAmount("Hello World");
```

---

### UPDATE

If the element definition is nested within your schema the name of the create method might be longer such as `createCardRequestAmount()`.

Comment: Every example I've seen suggest that I should see the ObjectFactory create method.  But I just don't see one for createAmount, just the CardRequest class itself.  But your 1st solution worked perfectly!  I'll be sure to accept when the time expires.

Comment: @EdgeCase - If `amount` is an element that is very nested in the XML schema the create method may be called something longer.  Can you search your `ObjectFactory` for create methods that contain `amount`?

Comment: Yep!  Exactly as you describe.  Found "createCardRequestAmount()"  Thanks a million.

Comment: What is the package name for ObjectFactory? I find 10 different ObjectFactory's when attempting to import. Not sure what to use.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing There's an ObjectFactory for every package that was created by xjc, you need the ObjectFactory in the same package as the class you're trying to instantiate.

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken, I figured it eventually. Thanks for pointing it though. Someone will benefit from this info for sure.