# How to Instantiate and store values in List<JAXBElement<?>>

Tags: java, list, soap, jaxbelement

I have generated java client from a Wsdl. I am stuck at following code where I have to set some setters values in following `List<JAXBElement<?>>`

```
public class SampleVerificationDomain
       extends BaseDomain
    {

       protected List<JAXBElement<?>> rest;

       /**
         * Gets the rest of the content model. 
         *  
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the rest property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getRest().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         *  
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link DummyVerification }{@code >}
         * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
         *
         */
        public List<JAXBElement<?>> getRest() {
            if (rest == null) {
                rest = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
            }
            return this.rest;
        }
```

I know how to store values if it is `List<Class>` or `List<String>` etc,
but how can I store value in a `JAXBElement` of type `<?>` and then store it in a List ?

**UPDATE:**

With help of this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548424/9811170], I have found ObjectFacotry class, which contains create functions of the values that needs to be set.

```
JAXBElement<?> jasbElem = null;     
jasbElem =  objectFactory.createSampleVerificationDomainCNIC("2392923");
jasbElem =  objectFactory.createSampleVerificationDomainMSISDN("xxxxxxx");
jasbElem =  objectFactory.createSampleVerificationDomainMsg("some message");
jasbElem =  objectFactory.createSampleVerificationDomainUserName("apiusername");
jasbElem =  objectFactory.createSampleVerificationDomainPassword("testpass");


SampleTestVerificationDomain.getRest().add(jasbElem);
```

But the above code only sets the last value in the JAXBElement.
Any help on how to store all the values in JAXBElement ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this: https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-root-elements

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.customer");
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    // Create Domain Objects
    AddressType billingAddress = new AddressType();
    billingAddress.setStreet("1 Any Street");
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);

    // Marshal Customer
    marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

    // Marshal Billing Address
    ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<AddressType> je =  objectFactory.createBillingAddress(billingAddress);
    marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
```